# How to get number of results by using file_get_contents

Tags: php, mysql

I have php file named `http://example.com/result.php?site=qxvyp6g6vefmt6tduifcr3swhuzo0uju&num=2`
which when executed, given only top 2 results. Here num is variable and can be changed to any value n to get top n results. This works fine when called from browser address bar.

Now i use to get this file content by

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/result.php?site=" . $_GET["site"] . "&num="2"");
?>
```

On a page having url ABC.com/index.php?site=qxvyp6g6vefmt6tduifcr3swhuzo0uju

This was working fine before adding &num="2" to file_get_contents. but after adding this gives a mysql error. Kindly help.

Comment: * but after adding this gives a mysql error.* -> what error ?
Consider to encode your site with something like `urlencode()` (resp. `urldecode()`)

Comment: the error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 1

Comment: This is what you should do, `. "&num=2");`

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/result.php?site=" . $_GET["site"] . "&num="2"");
?>
```

like this

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/result.php?site=" . $_GET["site"] . "&num=2");
?>
```

Comment: @ParvinderSingh :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using "" inside "", so php thinks this is not a string. Replace the "" around the 2 with single ones (like '2') and it should work.